# couldn't import EditControl from react-leaflet-draw

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-draw

Versions:
leaftlet - 1.3.4

react-leaflet - 2.0.1

leaflet-draw - 1.0.4

react-leaflet-draw -0.19.8

Code:

```
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import { EditControl } from "react-leaflet-draw";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    center: [51.505, -0.091],
    zoom: 13
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <Marker position={this.state.center}>
            <Popup>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

Could not find dependency: '@react-leaflet/core' relative to '/node_modules/react-leaflet-draw/dist/esm/EditControl.js'

I tried upgrading to 3.x for react-leaflet but same error.

Answer (score 0):

Digging into the react-leaflet-draw repo is kind of confusing. The README shows an example of `import { Map } from 'react-leaflet'`, but the package.json shows a dependency of react-leaflet v3, which does not import `Map`, but rather `MapContainer`.  The source code and the example in that repo indeed show `import { MapContainer } from 'react-leaflet'`.

You may want to try a simple `npm install @react-leaflet/core`, and make sure you're using react-leaflet version 3, and importing `MapContainer`, not `Map`.

Comment: I suppose `EditControl` doesn't support react-leaflet 3.x

Comment: Well that's what's confusing.  I think it *does* support react-leaflet v3, but in order to import from @react-leaflet/core, you need to install it.  Did you try installing it?

Comment: Yes. I tried installing the core but after installation, it shows error within the package